# Restrict access to sftp server for user by IP address

Tags: openssh, sftp

I'm trying to restrict access to an existing sftp server to a user, to allow it log in only from an IP address, but it's not working. In my case, I'm trying to allow to user some_user to log in ONLY from 192.168.12.10.

This is my complete sshd_config file:

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
RSAAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding no
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
MACs hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
KerberosAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

Match User some_user, Address !192.168.12.10
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User some_user, Address 192.168.12.10
    ChrootDirectory /home/some_user/
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I got this configuration (the Match User sections) from this [page](https://dhtar.com/restrict-sftp-access-to-sftp-only-specific-ip-only-within-chroot-jail-and-monitor-with-full-logging.html).

But it's not working: I'm still able to log in from any IP address. I've also tried what is suggested in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344444/match-multiple-users-in-sshd-config) but to no avail.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your attention.

Best regards.

Comment: Why do you have two `Match User` entries for the same IP? Try to set `PubkeyAuthentication no`.

Comment: I took it from the example shown in the first link I included in the post. Anyway, I had also tried with an unique Match User section (with Address 192.168.12.20), but with the same results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem was to use the simpler solution of adding this
configuration line:

```
AllowUsers some_user@192.168.12.10 otherid1 otherid2
```

This allows `some_user` only from `192.168.12.10`, and otherid1, otherid2
from anywhere.

---

**Old answer**

There is perhaps a simpler and safer way to restrict SSH access to only certain
IP addresses on a machine.

**`/etc/hosts.allow`**

```
sshd,sshdfwd-X11: 192.168.12.10
```

**`/etc/hosts.deny`**

To refuse SSH connections from anyone not in the IP address listed:

```
sshd,sshdfwd-X11:ALL
```

**Restrict SSH access by username (optional)**

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the following:

```
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers      user1 user2 user3 etc
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

**Restart the ssh daemon for these changes to take effect**

```
service sshd restart
```

Comment: Thanks, but this sftp server is intended for several users (all of them allowed from any ip), and I only need the restriction for one of them. Thanks again.

Comment: This can be done by one line: `AllowUsers some_user@192.168.12.10 otherid1 otherid2`, to allow some_user only from 192.168.12.10 and otherid1, otherid2 from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. That's what I needed.

Comment: Done, sorry. Thanks.